# When I activate the urlManager in config, can my Yii project not find my self created js folders?

Tags: php, yii

My folder structure:

> -MyProject
>   --assets
>   --css
>   --fonts
>   --images
>   --js      **Get an error! cannot find this folder?** 
>   --protected 
>   --themes
>   --index.php

What should I change in my urlManager, so the project can find my self created folders?

This is how my urlmanager looks now:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(     
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

In my view I have included:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('js/MYSCRIPT.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/js/YOUR-SCRIPT.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

to embed your script in layout.
You can however access your script from your view with this part:

```
Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/js/YOUR-SCRIPT.js';
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, in my question to mention that I have included my js folder in my view. In this way : yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptfile('js/MYSCRIPT'); I will add it to my question immediately:-) But that's not the problem. The problem is when I want to use urlManager. When I run my website, then Yii cannot find my js folders? so the question is whether, is it something extra  I have to add in urlManager?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear to me what you mean with use urlmanager. It is supposed to route a request to the framework, meaning to compose a dynamic response. JS is usually not dynamically created. Maybe you can rephrase your question to make clear, what you want to achieve. Also it could help if you post your complete view.

Comment: Also note the first '/' in `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/js/YOUR-SCRIPT.js';` That might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can point to that folder like

```
 $jsFolder = Yii::app()->homeUrl . 'js/';
 $imagesFolder = Yii::app()->homeUrl . 'images/';// will give you : "/localhost/MyProject/images/"
```